# WP8 HERE Maps walking directions between two points using official HERE Maps app

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, nokia, here-launcher

Using the HERE Launchers how can I get walking directions between two locations when the user presses a button on my page? Can I use names of places rather than coordinates? Also what references do I need for that app and is it possible for these directions to be made available offline when a user downloads my app?

Comment: Does anyone know how? There is poor documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the HERE launchers are fire-and-forgot type service, so you can only launch the HERE maps with values, and that's it. So from your application point of view, you can not get the reply back, or even know whether the service worked fine.

So unless the HERE maps application gets an update which with the user could get the route details exported, there are no such functionality.

And as the coordinate is marked as mandatory for the Uri scheme used with the walk guidance navigation, you must define at least the destination, and you need to define it as coordinate. However, if you want to use an address, you could always use teh geocoding services from the Maps API to find the geocoordinates for any given address.